# .NET Core Session: Session state is getting empty with every new request

Tags: c#, session, .net-core, session-cookies, .net-5

I am using Angular 11 and .Net Core(5) Web API.

I set the key/value to the session, but it comes as empty in the next first request.

Can you help me how I can use Session in Net Core 5?

**Startup.cs (First Try: Not Working)**

***ConfigureService;***

```
 services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
```

***Configure;***

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        }
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "OfferAPI v1"));
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseCors("AllowAll");
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

---

**Startup.cs (Second Try: Not Working)**

***ConfigureService;***

```
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
services.AddSession();
```

***Configure;***

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        }
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "OfferAPI v1"));
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseCors("AllowAll");
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

Comment: you want use DistributedMemoryCache or Session?

Comment: I want use Session.